# Why do I have to press the key multiple times to move?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pygame

So, I am writing a game in python and pygame. I was wondering, How come I have to press the "w" key multiple times to move up? I want to be able to hold any key and that action would be repeated. Also, Why does my dagger not "swing" when the character is faced down? This site is making me mad, as I am unable to format my code correctly, so just download it please.

This is where to get all the files (including the .py file):
https://www.mediafire.com/folder/k9ai685abradg/DeadWorld_Infestation_2_18-10-39

I know how buggy it is, but I want to work on it over the summer and get some stuff done.

Comment: Please reduce your problem down to a minimal working code sample that reproduces the issue, and post it here, on StackOverflow, not externally. People are not going to download your whole game and debug the whole thing for you - it's unreasonable to expect them to.

Comment: I tried to put it up here, but I wasn't able to figure out how to to format the code. I guess it is unreasonable.

Comment: Then I suggest you read [the help, which explains how to format your posts with markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) - it is linked to here, and from the right hand side of the edit box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.event.get()` only notifies you if a state has changed, e.g. the state of your W-key changed to pressed. I assume that you're looking for `pygame.event.get()[K_w]` which tells you if a key is in a pressed-state. The details about that command can be found in the [pygame docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html%20pygame%20docs).